# What is the code for an rss reader that only accesses local content?

Tags: javascript, rss, intranet

I need an rss reader for viewing feeds on our Intranet.  The only rss readers I've found can only read web based feeds.  I want to place the rss reader within an `<iframe>` or `<object>` within my page.

Comment: What is the difference between a web based and a local feed? Any RSS reader should work with any kind of URL

Comment: I've tried many rss readers and they will not read the feed I have, it is not published on the web and does not access it.  And I know the feed works because I can load it in my browser.

Comment: @Pekka: if the reader on the internet can't access the URL of the feed, like one that's on a local network, it won't work.

Comment: @Kwebble ah,  now I see what he means. @sange can you use a server-side scripting language?

Comment: I can use server-side Javascript.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You need the RSS reader to be in the same zone as the feeds. So if you want a web-based RSS reader that can read feeds available on your company network, the web-based RSS reader also needs to be running within your network.

So if your feeds are delivered via:

```
http://mynetwork/feeds/feed.xml
http://mynetwork/feeds/feed2.xml
```

You could pop a web-based reader in the same place to display them all nicely...

```
http://mynetwork/feeds/reader/
```

If you want more help getting hold of a feed-reader that you can install on your network, please let me know what technology stack you are able to use.

Comment: Thanks, I guess I was placing the RSS Reader in the wrong location.